# Creating a plane attachment in java for arcore

Tags: java, arcore

I'm trying to create a plane attachment variable in java. But it keeps giving me an error.

```
private PlaneAttachment mTouches = new PlaneAttachment();
```

The ide is telling me to add parameters such as:
    private PlaneAttachment mTouches = new PlaneAttachment(Plane plane, Anchor anchor);

but it keeps giving me errors

Comment: Can you show us your PlaneAttachment class?

Comment: Is PlaneAttachment your own class? Looks like it has only one constructor with two variables, so pass plane, anchor objects to it.

Comment: Really hard to help if you have us guessing about PlaneAttachment.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to know is what the constructor is in Java. In your case, I'm assuming you were referring to the `PlaneAttachment` class that is in the sample app. The constructor of that class requires 2 parameters, 1 is in `Plane` type and another one is in `Anchor` type.

When you try instantiating the instance, you need to pass in these 2 parameters.